# Is there a name for someone who doesn't drink alcohol besides a teetotaler?

Tags: character-development

I'm creating a character who's father was an alchoholic and he is deathly afraid of becoming one as well. He abstains from alcohol completely and never will try it.

Comment: Why do you need a noun? Verbs (I don't drink, I never drink, I abstain completely) or adjectives (I'm sober, I'm in recovery) give you more flexibility.

Comment: I made up a new term. Should I post it as my answer below?

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is in the question: An abstainer.

I have been drunk precisely once in my life, as a teen. And I embarrassed myself badly, and almost accidentally hurt myself, and I never drank again.

I don't call myself anything, I just say I don't drink alcohol, or I'm not a drinker, or I don't like getting drunk or buzzed or high.

I also don't do any recreational or mind-altering drugs.

You don't need a name for that, it is a choice. I was never an alcoholic, I never tried drinking in moderation, I just realized from my first drunk that it wasn't worth risking my life and possibly the lives of others.

If you want to get the point across, instead of coming up with a shorthand for it, I'd suggest you give your character a chance to explain. It doesn't have to be my reason, your character may have learned their lesson from an alcoholic parent or relative that destroyed their own life, abused their children, lost their livelihood -- and so your character swore never to partake.

Or, perhaps your character recovered from some other inadvertent addiction, and knows alcohol is addictive, and refuses to even try it, because they know they have an addictive personality.

And other characters say, "oh, Mark just doesn't drink."

In fiction, you don't always have to get your point across in the fewest words, your audience wants to know how your characters tick. Just giving them a trait to memorize is not as satisfying to them as letting them in on something personal and specific to the character that *explains* that trait, and why Mark is adamant about not drinking, and would be hurt and betrayed if tricked into drinking, or would break off a relationship over drinking, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Mary's answer as far as it goes.  But there is a host (well, maybe only a handful) of other expressions you could use, depending on what impression you want to create of the character and of abstinence in general.  You might call him

- a tea-drinker
- a member of the Band of Hope
- a Rechabite
- a prohibitionist (esp if he is rather zealous in his abstinence)
- a rider on the wagon
- dry

and probably many other things

Comment: A prohibitionist is zealous in the abstinence of others, not just their own.

Comment: Several of these are now obscure, and might not be understood by many readers.

Answer (score 0):

Total abstainer from alcohol.

Or abstainer from alcohol, which might include some lapses.  But "total abstainer" covers it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

## A Few Ideas:

**Temperate/temperance**

**Abstinence/abstention** (more often applied to sex, though)

**Sobriety/sober**

**Methyphobia/dipsophobia/potophobia** : all slightly different definitions of the fear of drinking alcohol.

Answer (score 0):

Additional Terms are "Designate Driver (DD)" although normally this refers to people who don't drink on rotation so they can be a sober driver for friends, though if you don't drink because you don't like drinking, they can be a "perma DD".

There are a handful of religious faiths that are famous for their tenants on prohibiting alcohol (Mormonism and Islam are some of the most well known) so referring to someone as a member of such a faith in the context of why they don't drink may suffice.

"Sober" typically refers to a person who is not under the influence of any substance, including non-legal and legal drugs, and typically people who choose sobriety will be said to "keep sober".  People who do not drink (or do drugs) often will be said to be "living above the influence" although this is occasionally more associated with a recovering addict.

"Dry" typically refers to a legal restriction on the sale of alcohol rather than a personal choice not to drink (For example, many Muslim majority nations are "dry" and in the U.S. some counties are "dry counties" although this often refers to restrictions on the time alcohol can be sold (but not on imbibing of owned alcohols  (for example, Baltimore City is dry on Sundays before either noon or one pm.).).